# Метод открытия нового activity для большого количества Button

Tags: android, классы, activity, android-intent

Есть activity с 7 кнопками. При нажатии на каждую кнопку, будет открываться новое activity. Вопрос, как правильно прописать метод обработки нажатия кнопок, т.к. в методе указывается конкретное activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Two.class);
```

Возникает вопрос - нужно написать 7 методов, для каждого activity, либо можно написать один метод для всех 7-ми кнопок, но в параметры метода необходимо передавать объект - Class. Если последнее возможно, подскажите пожалуйста синтаксис. `private void setButtonBehavior(Class class){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для перехода с одного активити в другие 7, я бы посоветовал бы сделать нечто подобное.
В Вашей главной активити(MainActivity) прописать следующее:

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.buttonFirst:
                    start(FirstActivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSecond:
                    start(SecondActivity.class);
                    break;
                ...
                ...
                case R.id.buttonSeven:
                    start(SevenActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    buttonFirst = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFirst);
    buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    buttonSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSecond);
    buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    ...
    ...
    buttonSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSeven);
    buttonSeven.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

И ниже в этом же классе, дописать следующий метод:

```
private void start(Class activity) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаешь отдельно переменную

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent;
            switch view.getId(){
                case R.id.button1: {
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity_One.class);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.button2: {
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Two.class);
                    break
                }

                ...................
                ...................

                default: break;
            }
        }
    };
```

А потом устанавливаешь ее для кнопок:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
.......................
........................
```